# ArrayList Remove Duplicate Elements

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I am parsing JSON data into ListView using `ArrayList` and now i would like to know How do i `remove duplicate` entries from ArrayList before populating it into `ListView`.

Here is my **JSON**:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "city": "Delhi"
    },
    {
      "city": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
      "city": "Delhi"
    },
    {
      "city": "Mumbai"
    }    
  ]
}
```

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Destination> destinationArrayList;    
    MainAdapter adapter;
    EditText editText;
    Destination destination;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLocation);

        destinationArrayList = new ArrayList<Destination>();

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("my api link");

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new MainAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, destinationArrayList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);                       
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                ....
                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        destination = new Destination();                                                
                        destination.setCity(object.getString("city"));                          
                        destinationArrayList.add(destination);

                    }
                    return true;
                }

            ......
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Map instead?

Comment: @DhavalPatel i would like to make change in my existing code as i am familiar with it

Comment: Put your arraylist into a set it will remove all duplicate elements.. and then again make an arraylist

Comment: @Akash like can you show me the way ?

Comment: Use a TreeMap - no duplicates!

Comment: Exactly. As mentioned by @Akash, you should use a Set (HashSet for example) that guarantees that it will not have duplicates.

Comment: use HashSet<String> hs=new HashSet<>(list);

Comment: put changes here, that helps in existing code

Comment: Next time, please only paste the relevant part of the code -- how you fetch the JSON isn't relevant to this question. (Yes, that's a bit more effort, but it makes it a lot easier to help you, and we appreciate it!)

Comment: @Akash show how and where can i use your code in my existing one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashSet` for that. If you'r using a model class then you need to create a arraylist of your model class.

```
ArrayList<Destination> destinationArrayList = new ArrayList<Destination>();
Set<Destination> hashset = new HashSet<>(); 
hashset.addAll(destinationArrayList); 
destinationArrayList.clear(); 
destinationArrayList.addAll(hashset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a `Set<String>` of city names. As you see each city, add it to the set, and then only add it to your list if the `set.add(...)` method returned true (thus indicating that it was added to the set, which means it wasn't there before, which means it's the first time you've seen this city).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ArrayList into HashSet , and duplicate elements will be taken care of .

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `HashSet` it will remove the duplicates:

```
HashSet<string> hashset = new HashSet<>(destinationArrayList);
```

`hashset` will then have a unique list

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLocation);

    destinationArrayList = new ArrayList<Destination>();

    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("my api link");
    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    hs.addAll(destinationArrayList );
    destinationArrayList .clear();
    destinationArrayList .addAll(hs);

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new MainAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, destinationArrayList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You try this

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    List<String> withDuplicatesCities = new ArrayList<String>();
    withDuplicatesCities.add( "Dehli" );
    withDuplicatesCities.add( "Mumbai" );
    withDuplicatesCities.add( "Dehli" );
    withDuplicatesCities.add( "Mumbai" );

    List<String> withoutDuplicates = removeDuplicates( withDuplicatesCities );
    System.out.println( withoutDuplicates );

}

private static List<String> removeDuplicates( List<String> withDuplicatesCities )
{
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for( String city : withDuplicatesCities )
    {
        set.add( city );
    }
    newList.addAll( set );

    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
HashSet<String> hs=new HashSet<>(list);
```